Electronic structure of $\rm NH_3$
The nitrogen atom has seven electrons: two and two electrons are on $1s$ and $2s$ orbitals. These are spherical symmetric. There are three electrons on $2p$ orbitals. When $\rm NH_3$ is formed, this symmetry is changing because overall there is a tetrahedral symmetry. Could you explain how the symmetric $2s$ electrons become isolated at the vertex of the tetrahedron?

There's likely someone here who can answer this question, but you also might consider posting it on [chemistry.se] if you don't get a good answer here. More experts about electronic structure of molecules over there, I imagine.

Probably hybridization theory  will do the job if it is a more chemistry question than a physics question

They don’t actually become isolated, but approximately more isolated as a “lone pair” on nitrogen. This is best simply understood with hybridization theory, but a more complex LCAO MO treatment will much more accurately help you see the contributions to the overall wavefunction from each atom.

Matt Hanson: I would expect that 2s remains spherical, and the other three electrons with the hydrogen atoms form an equilateral triangle shape. But, there is a different shape.

It's indeed a (very basic) chemistry question. Lone pair would have to be core-like to have no effect on geometry (like the one in 1s). S and p valence orbitals in NH3 are mixed resulting in $sp^3$ orbitals.

Let me give you an unorthodox answer.
There is the periodic table of the elements with a periodicity of 2 - 8 - 8 - ... and there is a model by Gilbert N. Lewis that describes the distribution of electrons of the noble gas neon on the 8 corners of a cube.
There is also the VSPER theory:

The electron pairs (or groups if multiple bonds are present) are assumed to lie on the surface of a sphere centered on the central atom and tend to occupy positions that minimize their mutual repulsions by maximizing the distance between them.

Which is probably pretty much in line with Lewis.
On the other hand, there is the formula $2n^2$, which was miraculously transferred from the spectrum of hydrogen to the electron probability distribution in all atoms. With a Spherical Harmonic that follows the Carthesian coordinate system, which is a significant limitation.
Following Lewis and the facts of the periodic table of the elements, at least the spherical harmonics structure $l=3, m=2, l-m=1$ should also have been considered.
Long story short: The s-shell results from the formula $2n^2$ . However, this formula lacks any proof that the model can be extended beyond the excitation states of hydrogen. And in practice, further electron distributions are only calculated with the aid of thousands of additions and assumptions.
So if you assume that the s-electrons and the p-electrons have the same properties, you get molecular bonds in a completely natural way instead of sp-hybridizations. For the $sp^3$-hybridization, a tetrahedron in the corners of a cube - in the spirit of Lewis.

$CH_4$ is a molecule with „$sp^3$“-hybridisation

NH$_3$ does not have tetrahedral symmetry. NH$_4^+$ is tetrahedral. NH$_3$ has a doubly occupied sp$^3$ orbital in the fourth tetrahedral direction, loosely speaking.
